# Is there a standard DSL for data integrity validation?

Tags: java, python, validation, import-from-csv

I am faced with CSV files which come from clients and which can contain hundreds of thousands of rows. Is there a DSL (or wildly popular library in Java or Python) which can efficiently run calculations on this information, applying various rules to issue warnings and errors (user-configurable, of course)?

Comment: Python has a csv module builtin by standard. http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: I'm aware of the `csv` module and use it extensively, but it doesn't offer a grammar for data rules based on the input. I can write it in pure Python, but sometimes it's a pain compared to (for example) Excel formulas.  I'm hoping for something where I can set a few dozen rules and then iterate over them for each row.  The more readable the rules are, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Can you imagine a DSL that would do it? How will the rules look like?

Several months ago I worked on such  problem - in the end it turned out to be harder than it seemed first.

1. The first step was obvious - all
   rows were parsed and placed to the
   special data stuctures so I could
   work with them; the ones with
   missing fields were thrown out.
2. Every row had its current "strategy"
   property, and a list of possible
   strategies (Default action, Ignore,
   Force, Overwrite etc.)
3. At first all rows had their "strategy"
   property set to "Default".
4. Row processor checked that operation was
   possible, creating list of errors
   and warnings.
5. After processing
   and analyzing results every row that
   caused problems was given a list of
   alternate strategies the user could
   choose;

So, if there were any problems, user could change the row strategy (or just simply use "Ignore") and go back to step 4.

So, I'm curious at what step would such a DSL work?

Comment: I am picturing something along the lines of assertions, which would work without necessarily enabling actions to repair them within the app. This is an integrity check script, so actions must be taken on the reporting side rather than the app itself.  Something like this: `"Number of Paid Items" <= "Number of Reported Items" or fail with "Reported items is less than paid items."`  To call a function, perhaps: `"Home Phone Number" is Formatted as "Phone" or warn with "Home phone number is incorrectly formatted."`